# Dismiss dialog coming from outside my application

Tags: android-alertdialog, android

In my application I perform an operation which causes an internal Android app to pop up `AlertDialog` over my application.

Is it possible to somehow dismiss this `Dialog` programmatically? Unfortunately I can't find the access to this `Dialog` object.

I've tried overriding `onCreateDialog()` method in my `Activity`, but as my `Activity` is not an originator of `Dialog` window, this method is not being called when it pops up.

I was also thinking about getting list of all objects that appear on the screen, but I assume there's no such method?

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: @SweetWisher I asked a question which doesn't require any code, I don't have anything to show. Basically in my application - under some circumstances - an `AlertDialog` appears, but my application is not an originator of this `Dialog`. I'm asking if it's somehow possible to access this `Dialog` object. I'm not looking for straightforward way to do this, because I assume there's no such, but this is quite crucial for my application and I'd appreciate even a hint.

Comment: need to see your code without code nobody can helps you

Comment: you need to use interface to implement.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia What kind of interface to implement?

Comment: Give me 5 min I provide you a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding you are doing something that is requiring some user interaction, like bluetooth pairing, in which case this Dialog is brought up by the system... *possibly* (System Dialog) which is not controlled by you. To solve this...

One thing you can try is:

```
Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
```

> public static final String ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
>
> Added in API level 1 Broadcast Action: This is broadcast when a user
>   action should request a temporary system dialog to dismiss. Some
>   examples of temporary system dialogs are the notification window-shade
>   and the recent tasks dialog.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS"

Comment: Will try it soon - seems promising!